# dplyr - Multiple summary functions

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to calculate multiple stats for a dataframe.

I tried `dplyr`'s `summarise_each`. However, the results are returned in a flat, single-row with the function's name added as a suffix.

Is there a direct way - using `dplyr` or base r - where I can get the results in a data frame, with the columns as the data frame's columns and the rows as the summary functions?

```
library(dplyr)

df = data.frame(A = sample(1:100, 20), 
                B = sample(110:200, 20), 
                C = sample(c(0,1), 20, replace = T))

df %>% summarise_each(funs(min, max)) 
# A_min B_min C_min A_max B_max C_max
# 1    13   117     0    98   188     1

# Desired format
summary(df)
# A               B               C       
# Min.   :13.00   Min.   :117.0   Min.   :0.00  
# 1st Qu.:34.75   1st Qu.:134.2   1st Qu.:0.00  
# Median :45.00   Median :148.0   Median :1.00  
# Mean   :52.35   Mean   :149.9   Mean   :0.65  
# 3rd Qu.:62.50   3rd Qu.:168.8   3rd Qu.:1.00  
# Max.   :98.00   Max.   :188.0   Max.   :1.00
```

Comment: close to this one? http://stackoverflow.com/q/38892219/3871924

Comment: @agenis Thank you! Yes, that's close. I was just wondering if there is a simpler way.

Comment: `summarise` returns one row per group, so without grouping it returns one row.

Comment: Maybe `data.frame(apply(df,2,summary))`

Answer (score 10):

How about:

```
library(tidyr)
gather(df) %>% group_by(key) %>% summarise_all(funs(min, max))
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 3 × 3
>     key   min   max
>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
> 1     A     2    92
> 2     B   111   194
> 3     C     0     1
> ```

Answer (score 10):

Why not just simply use `sapply` with `summary`?

```
sapply(df, summary)
```

gives:

> ```
>             A     B    C
> Min.     1.00 112.0 0.00
> 1st Qu. 23.75 134.5 0.00
> Median  57.00 148.5 1.00
> Mean    50.15 149.9 0.55
> 3rd Qu. 77.50 167.2 1.00
> Max.    94.00 191.0 1.00
> ```

To get a dataframe back, just wrap the `sapply` call in `data.frame()`: `data.frame(sapply(df, summary))`. If you want to keep summary statisticnames in a column, you can extract them with `rownames(df)` with `df$rn <- rownames(df)` or use the `keep.rownames`-parameter from `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(sapply(df, summary), keep.rownames = TRUE)
```

which gives:

> ```
> > dt
>         rn     A     B   C
> 1:    Min. 11.00 113.0 0.0
> 2: 1st Qu. 21.50 126.8 0.0
> 3:  Median 55.00 138.0 0.5
> 4:    Mean 53.65 145.2 0.5
> 5: 3rd Qu. 83.25 160.5 1.0
> 6:    Max. 98.00 193.0 1.0
> ```

Answer (score 4):

With the data.frame you proposed, and using the library `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
out <- df %>% map(~summary(.)) %>% rbind.data.frame
row.names(out) <- c("Min.", "1st Qu.", "Median", "Mean", "3rd Qu.", "Max.")
####             A     B   C
#### Min.     7.00 110.0 0.0
#### 1st Qu. 36.75 132.5 0.0
#### Median  53.50 143.5 0.5
#### Mean    55.45 151.8 0.5
#### 3rd Qu. 82.00 167.0 1.0
#### Max.    99.00 199.0 1.0
```

There you go. let me just mention that this code works for input data.frame with 100% numeric variables only. It will return an error if there is for instance, a character/factor variable, since the output of summary is quite different.

Answer (score 2):

It is not the only way to go but you could reshape your data.frame as you want using `dplyr` and `tidyr`. (and `stringr` or other to trim character.)

```r
library(dplyr)

df = data.frame(A = sample(1:100, 20), 
                B = sample(110:200, 20), 
                C = sample(c(0,1), 20, replace = T))

as_data_frame(summary(df)) %>%
  # some blank character could be trim
  mutate(Var2 = stringr::str_trim(Var2)) %>% 
  # you don't need Var1
  select(-Var1) %>%
  # Get the type of summary and the value
  tidyr::separate(n, c("Type", "value"), sep = ":") %>%
  # Convert value to numeric
  mutate(value = as.numeric(value)) %>%
  # reshape as you wish
  tidyr::spread(Var2, value, drop = T)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#>      Type     A     B     C
#> *   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 1st Qu. 36.25 122.2  1.00
#> 2 3rd Qu. 77.25 164.5  1.00
#> 3 Max.    95.00 193.0  1.00
#> 4 Mean    57.30 144.6  0.85
#> 5 Median  63.00 143.5  1.00
#> 6 Min.     8.00 111.0  0.00
```

Answer (score 1):

An approach without using `tidyr` nor `dplyr`:

```
df <- data.frame(A = sample(1:100, 20), 
                 B = sample(110:200, 20), 
                 C = sample(c(0,1), 20, replace = T))
df %>% 
    lapply(summary) %>% 
    do.call("rbind", .)
```

Output:

```
  Min. 1st Qu. Median   Mean 3rd Qu. Max.
A    9    32.5   50.5  49.65   70.25   84
B  116   137.2  162.5 157.70  178.20  196
C    0     0.0    0.0   0.45    1.00    1
```

If you want to do it with `dplyr`, try:

```
df %>% 
    gather(attribute, value) %>% 
    group_by(attribute) %>% 
    do(as.data.frame(as.list(summary(.$value))))
```

Output:

```
Source: local data frame [3 x 7]
Groups: attribute [3]

  attribute  Min. X1st.Qu. Median   Mean X3rd.Qu.  Max.
      <chr> <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
1         A     9     32.5   50.5  49.65    70.25    84
2         B   116    137.2  162.5 157.70   178.20   196
3         C     0      0.0    0.0   0.45     1.00     1
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all very much for your help! After some cherry-picking, I used the following method.

```
# Dataframe 
df = data.frame(A = sample(1:100, 20), 
                B = sample(110:200, 20), 
                C = sample(c(0,1), 20, replace = T))

# Add summary functions to a list
summaryFns = list(
  NA.n  = function(x) sum(is.na(x)),
  NA.percent = function(x) sum(is.na(x))/length(x),
  unique.n = function(x) ifelse(sum(is.na(x)) > 0, length(unique(x)) - 1, length(unique(x))),
  min = function(x) min(x, na.rm=TRUE),
  max = function(x) max(x, na.rm=TRUE))


# Summarise data frame with each function 
# Using dplyr:
library(dplyr)
sapply(summaryFns, function(fn){df %>% summarise_all(fn)})
#   NA.n NA.percent unique.n min max
# A 0    0          20       1   98 
# B 0    0          20       114 200
# C 0    0          2        0   1  

# Using base-r:
sapply(summaryFns, function(fn){sapply(df, fn)})
#     NA.n NA.percent unique.n min max
# A    0          0       20   1  98
# B    0          0       20 114 200
# C    0          0        2   0   1
```

I think that is the most straight forward and flexible method.
Further comments, modifications and suggestions are appreciated.